# SQL - Adding a summary of results

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have a script that returns results based on one or many conditions. There are around 20 or so columns that could have a result. Is there a way to add a summary column at the end to indicate which columns have a value for each record?

Edit: SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: can you add what version of SQL Server are you using?. Also please post an example of the result that you want

Comment: Your question is a little ambiguous.  Sample data and desired results are more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a guess, but here is one approach that will use a little XML to solve this problem

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table (ID int,Col1 varchar(50),Col2 varchar(50),Col3 varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'HasValue',null,null)
,(2,'HasValue',null,'ValueHere')


Select A.*
      ,C.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml))) B(XMLData)
 Cross Apply (
               Select Columns = Stuff((Select ',' +Item 
                From  (
                        Select Item  = xAttr.value('local-name(.)', 'varchar(100)')
                              ,Value = xAttr.value('.','varchar(max)')
                         From  XMLData.nodes('//@*') xNode(xAttr)
                         Where xAttr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('ID','OtherColumns','ToExclude')
                       )C1
                For XML Path ('')),1,1,'') 
             ) C
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Col1        Col2    Col3        Columns
1   HasValue    NULL    NULL        Col1
2   HasValue    NULL    ValueHere   Col1,Col3
```

Answer (score 0):

Not as convenient of a solution as John's, but here is a brute-force version that will work on older version of SQL Server.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (
    Col1 BIT,
    Col2 BIT,
    Col3 BIT
)

INSERT INTO @t SELECT 1,NULL,NULL
INSERT INTO @t SELECT NULL,1,NULL
INSERT INTO @t SELECT NULL,NULL,1

SELECT
    *
    ,    CASE WHEN Col1 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Col1: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),Col1) ELSE '' END
        +CASE WHEN Col2 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Col2: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),Col2) ELSE '' END
        +CASE WHEN Col3 IS NOT NULL THEN 'Col3: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),Col3) ELSE '' END
    AS [Summary]
FROM @t
```